# Remote Icinga instance 'xxx' is not connected to 'zzzz'

Tags: icinga, icinga2

I have Icinga2 installed including Director.
I've added a template, service and a Windows, installed an agent on the host but there's something that I must be missing.

I keep getting

> "Remote Icinga instance 'xxx' is not connected to 'zzz'"

,
although communication is perfectly fine (same subnet, no firewalls, communication verified with telnet on port 5665).

Here's a screenshot from the WEB GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was communication.
Had to open port 5665 from master to client.